# How to export chart as picture with highest resolution

Tags: excel, vba, image, charts, export

I have the written the following code to select a range and create a chart. Chart is later exported as picture. It works, However the clarity of the picture is very bad as the range selected is from A2:U111. The code that am using is.

```
Dim sSheetName2 As String
Dim sSheetName3 As String
Dim oRangeToCopy As Range
Dim oCht As Chart
Dim comm As String
Workbooks("Workbook").Activate

Worksheets("Worksheet").Activate
sSheetName2 = "Worksheet" ' worksheet to work on



Worksheets(sSheetName2).Range("A2:U111").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
Set oCht = Charts.Add
Charts("Chart1").Activate
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 400
With oCht
    .Paste
    .Export Filename:="D:\rr.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
End With
```

I have also tried to reduce the range size, yet it gets pixelated.

Comment: you can export as a 1 page wide pdf

Comment: my intention is to append this picture on to the mail body

Comment: @QHarr Can you share the code to export a excel to pdf in one wide sheet?

Comment: I’m currently on way to airport. You should be able to google export image as pdf excel vba. If not, I will have a look. I ran it at a test using a range of your dimensions and it worked. Just was over a lot of pages. Stopped before I worked out whether that could be shrunk to a page.

Comment: @QHarr  No problem. I figured a way out. there was minor mistake in the code itself. Thank

Comment: Great. Post as answer. Would be nice to see. May have need of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sSheetName2 As String
Dim sSheetName3 As String
Dim oRangeToCopy As Range
Dim oCht As Chart
Dim comm As String
Workbooks("workbook").Activate

Worksheets("worksheet").Activate
Range("A2:U111").Select
With Selection.Font
    .Size = 9
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
sSheetName2 = "worksheet" ' worksheet to work on
Worksheets(sSheetName2).Range("A2:U20").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
Set oCht = Charts.Add
oCht.Activate
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 400
With oCht
    .Paste
    .Export Filename:="D:\rr.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
End With
```

I was running the code multiple times and the code was zooming in the chart1 as mentioned in the code.

```
 oCht.Activate
 ActiveWindow.Zoom = 400
 With oCht
     .Paste
     .Export Filename:="D:\rr.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
 End With
```

Now it selects the chart that was recently created. I have also increased the font size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in C# by saving the chart to .emf. Then I open the .emf file and convert the content to a `Bitmap` object and then to a `BitmapSource` object. The reason is this acts as an enhanced version of `Excel.Chart.CopyPicture` and the user should be able to paste the result image in the clipboard.

I assume you know how to create a Excel VSTO project and already have a Excel ribbon, which contains a button invoking the following `OnActionClick` method in `Ribbon.cs`:

```
public void OnActionClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    var chart = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application?.ActiveChart;

    if (chart == null)
        return;

    chart.CopyPicture(
        Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen,
        Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlPicture,
        Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen);

    ImageHelper.ImproveClipboardImageQuality();
}
```

And here is `ImageHelper.cs`:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Drawing;
> using System.Drawing.Imaging;
> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
> using System.Windows;
> using System.Windows.Media;
> using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
> using PixelFormat = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat;
>
> namespace ExcelAddIn1
> {
>     [ComVisible(false)]
>     public static class ImageHelper
>     {
>         [DllImport("user32.dll")]
>         public static extern long CloseClipboard();
>
>         [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
>         public static extern long CopyEnhMetaFileA(long hemfSrc, string lpszFile);
>
>         [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
>         public static extern long DeleteEnhMetaFile(long hdc);
>
>         [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
>         internal static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
>
>         [DllImport("user32.dll")]
>         public static extern long GetClipboardData(long uFormat);
>
>         [DllImport("user32.dll")]
>         public static extern long OpenClipboard(long hwnd);
>
>         private static string GetTemporaryImageFileFullPath() => ".\\TemporaryImageFile.emf";
>
>         // https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/62521f13-8edb-4490-9a81-b337d6ee876f/how-to-export-excel-sheet-to-jpgpng-with-high-resolution-in-vba?forum=isvvba&prof=required
>         private static void ExportClipboardImageToEmf(string emfFileName)
>         {
>             OpenClipboard(0);
>
>             var clipboardData = GetClipboardData(14);
>             var copiedEnhMetaFile = CopyEnhMetaFileA(clipboardData, emfFileName);
>
>             if (DeleteEnhMetaFile(copiedEnhMetaFile) == 0)
>                 throw new Exception("Failed to delete the enhanced meta file");
>
>             CloseClipboard();
>         }
>
>         private static Bitmap EmfToBitmap(string path)
>         {
>             using (var emf = new Metafile(path))
>             {
>                 var bmp = new Bitmap(emf);
>                 bmp.SetResolution(emf.HorizontalResolution, emf.VerticalResolution);
>                 return bmp;
>             }
>         }
>
>         private static BitmapSource Convert(Bitmap bitmap)
>         {
>             var outputPixelFormat = GetMatchingPixelFormat(bitmap.PixelFormat);
>
>             var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
>                 new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
>                 ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
>                 bitmap.PixelFormat);
>
>             var bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(
>                 bitmapData.Width,
>                 bitmapData.Height,
>                 bitmap.HorizontalResolution,
>                 bitmap.VerticalResolution,
>                 outputPixelFormat,
>                 null,
>                 bitmapData.Scan0,
>                 bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height,
>                 bitmapData.Stride);
>
>             bitmapSource.Freeze();
>             bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
>             return bitmapSource;
>         }
>
>         private static PixelFormat GetMatchingPixelFormat(System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pixelFormat)
>         {
>             var outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
>
>             switch (pixelFormat)
>             {
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Indexed:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Indexed8;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Gdi:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Alpha:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.PAlpha:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Extended:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Canonical:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Undefined:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Indexed1;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Indexed4;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Indexed8;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Gray16;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Bgr555;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Bgr565;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Bgr555;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Bgr32;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Bgra32;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Pbgra32;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Rgb48;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Rgba64;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format64bppPArgb:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Prgba64;
>                     break;
>                 case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Max:
>                     break;
>                 default:
>                     outputPixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
>                     break;
>             }
>
>             return outputPixelFormat;
>         }
>
>         private static BitmapSource BitmapToBitmapSource(Bitmap bitmap)
>         {
>             if (bitmap == null)
>                 return null;
>
>             var hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
>             BitmapSource source = null;
>
>             try
>             {
>                 source = Convert(bitmap);
>             }
>             catch (Exception)
>             {
>                 // Trace Error:
>                 // $"Failed to create bitmap image source from file path {hBitmap.ToInt32()}. Details: {ex.Message}"
>             }
>             finally
>             {
>                 DeleteObject(hBitmap);
>             }
>
>             source.Freeze();
>
>             return source;
>         }
>
>         public static void ImproveClipboardImageQuality()
>         {
>             var emfFileName = GetTemporaryImageFileFullPath();
>             ExportClipboardImageToEmf(emfFileName);
>             var bitmap = EmfToBitmap(emfFileName);
>             var bitmapSource = BitmapToBitmapSource(bitmap);
>             Clipboard.SetImage(bitmapSource);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```